# C++ inheritance question

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a class like so:

```
class A
{
   public:
      virtual void foo() { bar() }

   protected:  
      virtual void bar() { /* do stuff */ }
}
```

Now I want a derived class B that overrides both foo and bar. So I wrote the following:

```
class B : public A 
{
    public: 
        virtual void foo() { A::foo(); /* then other stuff */ }

    protected:
       virtual void bar() { /* do different stuff */ }
}
```

Everything compiles but when I invoke B::foo I expect B::bar to get (eventually) called. Instead, I get A::bar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to increment all your pointers by 42.

Comment: How did you declare your instance of "B"

Comment: Could you show us how you are calling them ?

Comment: how are you calling the method? (include your main method too)

Comment: Where are you calling bar from?

Comment: Hi. I added an example implementation.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for adding more code, but what we want to see is how you are creating a `B` object and calling `foo` on it, e.g. an example `main()` function.

Answer (score 9):

> Everything compiles but when I invoke B::foo I expect B::bar to get (eventually) called. Instead, I get A::bar. What am I doing wrong?

Looks like you didn't really understand what went wrong in your **original code**, decided that the virtual override mechanism must be the culprit and then you posted a **non-working example** which describes what you are **inclined to believe**, but which you **didn't bother** to check, because if you had then you'd seen that it **does not expose the described behavior**. here's a compileable version of your example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
class A
{
   public:
      virtual void foo() { puts("A:foo()"); bar(); }

   protected:  
      virtual void bar() { puts("A:bar()"); }
};

class B : public A 
{
    public: 
        virtual void foo() { puts("B:foo()"); A::foo(); }

    protected:
       virtual void bar() {  puts("B:bar()");  }
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    b.foo();
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
$ g++ g++ h.cc
$ ./a.out
B:foo()
A:foo()
B:bar()
```

So everything's fine with B::bar().

Comment: Indeed. The problem is either with the code that creates the object and calls the function (which we haven't been shown), or with the interpretation of the results.

Answer (score 2):

## before the update by the op.

This should work

```
A* b = new B();

b->bar(); //Notice that this is just an example
```

Also works with references

```
void B::foo(){this->bar();}

  B b;
  A& ab = b;
  ab.foo(); //calls B::bar()
```

Comment: Your update doesn't make any sense. If he *were* calling `A::bar` explicitly, this would be correct (although the `this->` is still superfluous), however take another look at his code: he's calling `A::foo` explicitly, which in turn calls `bar()` normally. Since `bar` is virtual, this should resolve to `B::bar` as he expects.

Comment: b->bar() will not work as the member is protected. Your re-definition of B::foo() is not what the OP wants. He wants it to call the base implementation of A::foo() first.

Comment: @Martin, it was written before the example given by the op. The first snippet of code was writen to show the point about pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the missing semicolons at the end of the class definitions, the current OP code works as intended.